# For each $k$, does ther exist a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$ such that $ker(T^k) = Im(T^k)$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$. For each positive integer $k$, does there is a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$,  such that $ker(T^k) = Im(T^k)$ ?.

For $k=1$, such a linear map exist. What about for $k >1$ ?

Comment: What if  n=dim V is odd?

Comment: @MathChat  for $k=1$, $dim(V)$ is even.